# Flask-Restx(/Flask-Restplus) detect reload

Tags: python-3.x, flask-restplus, flask-restx

my problem is the following: In my Flask-Restx-Application I created a Runner-Thread which runs asynchronously to the main-thread of the Flask-Application.

Now when I do changes as usual the Debugger still shows `* Detected change in 'XXXXX', reloading` which is  a useful feature. The problem is that now it got stuck and cannot reload because of the running Thread which must be stopped manually.

I would still like to use the automatic reload if possible in combination with the asynchronous Runner-Thread. Is there a possibility to "detect" those reloads by triggering an Event or something similar? Then I could manually shutdown the Runner-Thread and restart it with the application. Or is there at least a possibility to not block the reload in order to proceed reloading the flask-restx-related stuff?

Thanks in advance for any help.

PS: I find it hard to add code here because I do not know which parts of the flask-app are important. If you need any code to answer the question I will add it in an Edit.

Comment: Btw. I could not tag it with the better fitting 'flask-restx' tag because it does not exist, yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your thread a daemon thread if you want the reloader to work. The reloader will try to kill and restart the program (by killing the main thread), but because your other thread is not a daemon, it will fail to kill the program and reload it. A daemon thread is one that only lives as long as the main thread lives, and therefore making your other thread a daemon will fix your issue. Here is an example:

```
from threading import Thread

...

t = Thread(...)
t.daemon = True # this makes your thread a daemon thread
t.start()
```